# Get parameter of GET request

Tags: javascript, http, get, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I make a GET request:

```
 createXhrRequest( "GET", fileURL, function( err, response ) {
      if( err ) { alert( "Error GET!" ); }
      alert(response);
 });
```

and I get this full response:

> { "status" : "ok", "message" :
>   "JVBERi0xLjQKJdDUxdgKMy

How can I get only `JVBERi0xLj`?

I try response.message , response["message"]. But nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just simple access it like this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(response);
json.message
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`
 

you know why?

Comment: Can you post full the response?

Comment: Full response on the question

Answer (score 1):

```
createXhrRequest( "GET", fileURL, function( err, response ) {
      if(err) { 
          alert("Error GET!"); 
          return;
      }
      try {
          var obj = JSON.parse(response);
          alert(obj.message);
      }
      catch (err) {
          alert("Error PARSE!");
      }           
 });
```

UPDATE : Above code works, when expected result is JSON string. 
But if your `createXhrRequest` returns a JS Object, then you can very well just use `alert(response.message);`

Comment: Then plz add the response

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 createXhrRequest( "GET", fileURL, function( err, response ) {
  if( err ) { alert( "Error GET!" ); }
  alert(response.message);

  });
```